# How to get the chart to display nothing when the value is N/A

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts

I created a VB.net program to display chart. The data is taken from the Excel workbook. So far, I got it to open and display the data on the chart, but some of my data in Excel is displayed as #N/A. The purpose of N/A is to show nothing on the chart. Here is what it looks like when I use Excel to display my chart:

[image: Charts]

In my workbook, the formula that I use to display the necessary point is =IF($B2>=$G2,$B2,NA()). As you can see on the image above, it display only the red points when there are value other than N/A. When the data is N/A, it show nothing on the chart.

With the VB program, it show everything, even the value N/A. Here is what it looks like: 
[image]

It's totally messed up. I don't know how to get rid the other points and just display the points that looks like in the first image. 
Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
'Add reference Assemblies, Framework, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim excelWS As Excel.Worksheet

    'Dim FNameRng As Excel.Range
    Dim AveRng As Excel.Range
    Dim A_CLRng As Excel.Range
    Dim A_UCLRng As Excel.Range
    Dim A_LCLRng As Excel.Range
    Dim A_GTRng As Excel.Range
    Dim A_LTRng As Excel.Range

    'Dim FNameArry As System.Array
    Dim AveArry As System.Array
    Dim A_CLArry As System.Array
    Dim A_UCLArry As System.Array
    Dim A_LCLArry As System.Array
    Dim A_GTArry As System.Array
    Dim A_LTArry As System.Array

    excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    excelApp.Visible = False

    'Open the Workbook
    excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Joesph\Documents\Charts\Control Limit\Test 18x17 - 10 mil stop.xlsx")
    excelWS = excelApp.Sheets("10 mil stop")

    'Set the Range for File Name
    'FNameRng = excelWS.Range("A2", excelWS.Range("A2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    'Set the Range for Average Data
    AveRng = excelWS.Range("B2", excelWS.Range("B2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    A_CLRng = excelWS.Range("F2", excelWS.Range("F2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    A_UCLRng = excelWS.Range("G2", excelWS.Range("G2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    A_LCLRng = excelWS.Range("H2", excelWS.Range("H2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    A_GTRng = excelWS.Range("I2", excelWS.Range("I2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))
    A_LTRng = excelWS.Range("J2", excelWS.Range("J2").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown))

    'Read in the values of a range of cells
    'FNameArry = CType(FNameRng.Value, System.Array)
    AveArry = CType(AveRng.Value, System.Array)
    A_CLArry = CType(A_CLRng.Value, System.Array)
    A_UCLArry = CType(A_UCLRng.Value, System.Array)
    A_LCLArry = CType(A_LCLRng.Value, System.Array)
    A_GTArry = CType(A_GTRng.Value, System.Array)
    A_LTArry = CType(A_LTRng.Value, System.Array)

    'Set the chart title
    Me.CenterToScreen()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    Chart1.Titles.Add("Title1")
    Chart1.Titles(0).Text = "Average"
    Chart1.Titles(0).Font = New Font("Garamond", 24, FontStyle.Bold)
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90

    'Looping through the AveArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To AveArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To AveArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim Average As Object = AveArry(x, y)
            Chart1.Series("Average").Points.Add(Average)
        Next y
    Next x

    'Looping through the A_CLArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_CLArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_CLArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim AveCL As Object = A_CLArry(x, y)
            Chart1.Series("Mean of Means").Points.Add(AveCL)
        Next y
    Next x

    'Looping through the A_UCLArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_UCLArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_UCLArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim AveUCL As Object = A_UCLArry(x, y)
            Chart1.Series("UCL (3-Sigma)").Points.Add(AveUCL)
        Next y
    Next x

    'Looping through the A_LCLArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_LCLArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_LCLArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim AveLCL As Object = A_LCLArry(x, y)
            Chart1.Series("LCL (3-Sigma)").Points.Add(AveLCL)
        Next y
    Next x

    'Looping through the A_GTArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_GTArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_GTArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim AveGT As Object = A_GTArry(x, y)
            For iPt = 1 To Chart1.Series("GT_UCL").Points.Count
                If IsNumeric(A_LTArry(iPt, 1)) Then
                    'Chart1.Series("GT_UCL").Points.Add(AveGT)
                    Chart1.Series("GT_UCL").Points(iPt).MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond
                Else
                    Chart1.Series("GT_UCL").Points(iPt).MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None
                End If
            Next
        Next y
    Next x

    'Looping through the A_LTArry
    For x As Integer = 1 To A_LTArry.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 1 To A_LTArry.GetUpperBound(1)
            Dim AveLT As Object = A_LTArry(x, y)
            For iPt = 1 To Chart1.Series("LT_LCL").Points.Count
                If IsNumeric(A_LTArry(iPt, 1)) Then
                    'Chart1.Series("LT_LCL").Points.Add(AveLT)
                    Chart1.Series("LT_UCL").Points(iPt).MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Diamond
                Else
                    Chart1.Series("LT_LCL").Points(iPt).MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None
                End If
            Next
        Next y
    Next x

    excelApp.Workbooks.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**
I edited the code for the last two loops. It got better, but now it won't display the red points. Is the order wrong or something? Here's what it looks like now: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two links that Jon Peltier posted a few days ago:
http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/vba-approaches-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/
http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/another-approach-plotting-gaps-excel-charts/

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying the points as two separate series, one for all of the data and one for just the outliers? It looks like your limits are calculated based on just the outliers.

Here is an ancient example that shows how to highlight the min and max values in a chart: [Custom Format for Chart Minimum and Maximum](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/FormatMinMax.html). The concept is the same: plot all points in main series, then overlay differently formatted points only where desired.